# How to perform different operation in button click in list view which use custom layout as Adopter?

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I'm using List View which use custom layout and the layout consist of two textview and two button.
here is code. . .

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/border_week_flash_card" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_margin="12dp"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bPractice_deck"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/txt_title"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="@drawable/week_button"
        android:onClick="startSwipeViewActiviy"
        android:text="Practice this deck ->" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_progress"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/bPractice_deck"
        android:layout_margin="12dp"
        android:text="See Your progress by test . . ."
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/txt_progress"
        android:background="@drawable/week_button"
        android:text="Take test to see progress->" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

and my Main java code is . . . .

```
    public class Course_Week extends ListActivity {
    Button bPractice;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        final Context context = this;
        // bPractice=(Button)findViewById(R.id.bPractice_deck);
        final String[] course = { "Week 1", "Week 2", "Week 3", "Week 4", "Week 5",
                "Week 6", "Week 7", "Week 8", "Week 9", "Week 10", "Week 11",
                "Week 12" };
        ArrayAdapter<String> adopter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                R.layout.week_flash_card, R.id.txt_title, course) {
            @Override
            public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                    View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.week_flash_card, parent, false);
                    TextView textView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.txt_title);
                    //ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
                    textView.setText(course[position]);
                    // Change the icon for Windows and iPhone
                    switch(postion){
                        case 0:
                            //when button on first week click
                            break;
                        case 1:
                            //when button on 2nd week click
                            break;
                        }

                    return rowView;

            }
        };
        setListAdapter(adopter);

    }
}
```

Problem is that i don't have any idea how to implement the onclick operation as i want to perform different operation on click of each differen list button .. 
i.e I want to perform different operation when clicking "practice this deck" button of week1 and different when pressing week2 "practice this deck button" . .

```
06-28 22:21:49.003: E/AndroidRuntime(14739): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-28 22:21:49.003: E/AndroidRuntime(14739): Process: com.saru.chaudhary.wpmeasy, PID: 14739
06-28 22:21:49.003: E/AndroidRuntime(14739): java.lang.NullPointerException
06-28 22:21:49.003: E/AndroidRuntime(14739):    at com.saru.chaudhary.wpmeasy.Course_Week$1.getView(Course_Week.java:37)
06-28 22:21:49.003: E/AndroidRuntime(14739):    at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2255)
06-28 22:21:49.003: E/AndroidRuntime(14739):    at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1790)
06-28 22:21:49.003: E/AndroidRuntime(14739):    at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:691)
06-28 22:21:49.003: E/AndroidRuntime(14739):    at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:752)
06-28 22:21:49.003: E/AndroidRuntime(14739):    at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1630)
06-28 22:21:49.003: E/AndroidRuntime(14739):    at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2087)
06-28 22:21:49.003: E/AndroidRuntime(14739):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14860)
06-28 22:21:49.003: E/AndroidRuntime(14739):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4643)
06-28 22:21:49.003: E/AndroidRuntime(14739):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
06-28 22:21:49.003: E/AndroidRuntime(14739):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
06-28 22:21:49.003: E/AndroidRuntime(14739):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14860)
06-28 22:21:49.003: E/AndroidRuntime(14739):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4643)
06-28 22:21:49.003: E/AndroidRuntime(14739):    at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onLayout(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:374)
06-28 22:21:49.003: E/AndroidRuntime(14739):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14860)
06-28 22:21:49.003: E/AndroidRuntime(14739):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4643)
06-28 22:21:49.003: E/AndroidRuntime(14739):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
06-28 22:21:49.003: E/AndroidRuntime(14739):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
06-28 22:21:49.003: E/AndroidRuntime(14739):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14860)
06-28 22:21:49.003: E/AndroidRuntime(14739):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4643)
06-28 22:21:49.003: E/AndroidRuntime(14739):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2013)
06-28 22:21:49.003: E/AndroidRuntime(14739):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1770)
06-28 22:21:49.003: E/AndroidRuntime(14739):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1019)
06-28 22:21:49.003: E/AndroidRuntime(14739):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5725)
06-28 22:21:49.003: E/AndroidRuntime(14739):    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
06-28 22:21:49.003: E/AndroidRuntime(14739):    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
06-28 22:21:49.003: E/AndroidRuntime(14739):    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:544)
06-28 22:21:49.003: E/AndroidRuntime(14739):    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
06-28 22:21:49.003: E/AndroidRuntime(14739):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
06-28 22:21:49.003: E/AndroidRuntime(14739):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
06-28 22:21:49.003: E/AndroidRuntime(14739):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
06-28 22:21:49.003: E/AndroidRuntime(14739):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5086)
06-28 22:21:49.003: E/AndroidRuntime(14739):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-28 22:21:49.003: E/AndroidRuntime(14739):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
06-28 22:21:49.003: E/AndroidRuntime(14739):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
06-28 22:21:49.003: E/AndroidRuntime(14739):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
06-28 22:21:49.003: E/AndroidRuntime(14739):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: You handle onClick in the adapter and set it's functionality based on it's position in the adapter.

Comment: after implementing my adopter i do like this
switch(positon){
case 0:
operation 
break;
}
case 2:.....
but this will not work as my app stop working

Comment: I would need to see why it is crashing. Could you post your log stack trace?

Comment: i have edited my post so you can see logcat report

Comment: getView(Course_Week.java:37)... what is line 37 in the method getView() of the class Course_Week?

Comment: 36--button = (Button) convertView
     37--.findViewById(R.id.bPractice_deck);

Comment: Do you do a check to make sure convertView != null?

Comment: sir let me again post my activity code and then tell me where to write switch case and implement clikable operation

Comment: It needs to be in your adapter, not in your activity :)

Comment: now can u check my mainactivity code and see if anything wrong

Comment: I will post it as an answer since it will take up more than a comment will allow

Comment: can't u post in answer section  ..

if not possible use 2 or more comment whatever u need . .please

Comment: ... I did post in answer section

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. Not tested, but should work:

```
final Context context = this;
ArrayAdapter<String> adopter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            R.layout.week_flash_card, R.id.txt_title, course)
{
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
        //convertView = context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE).inflate(R.layout.week_flash_card, null);
        Button button = convertView.findViewById(R.id.bPractice_deck);
        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0)
            {
                switch(position)
                {
                    case 0:
                    {
                        // your code goes here
                        break;
                    }
                    case 1:
                    {
                        // your code goes here
                        break;
                    }
                    // etc...
                }

            }
        });
        return convertView;
    }
};
setListAdapter(adopter);
```

Comment: thanks for help but as i use that custom layout for 12 time i.e week1 to 12 . i want to perform different operation on click button on different week view . .

Comment: @saru you can do that by using getView's position variable.

Comment: i'm doing like this
switch(positon){
case 0:
operation 
break;
}
case 2:.....
but this will not work as my app stop working

Comment: i have changed my code a lot now . what i want is after setting my custom adaptor and use it for 12 week this will look like this 
http://imgur.com/MToD6UL
and now i want to click on these button so that each button in each week will work diferently 
i try ur code but all the button perform same operation and don't know what to do if i do some switch inside the view method and that will result in crash of my app

Comment: as i declare onclick method "startswipeview" if i use that method for operation without setting or getting tag in getView method then it'll work.
and without any switch case

Comment: @saru I updated the code, added switch statements. If it crashes, it is because of the code you put in switch statement, not because of switch statement itself.

Comment: i just print the toast message inside the case to test it but it doesn't seem to work

Comment: show me the line of code that makes your app crash.

Comment: ok,sorry my mistake there is problem with the button i refer now it work fine thanks for ur time sir,thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0):

`// bPractice=(Button)findViewById(R.id.bPractice_deck);` causes an error (if it isn't commented of course) because you don't have a layout set for your activity yet.

-To fix:

- Move it below `TextView textView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.txt_title);` in getView()
- change it to `bPractice=(Button) rowView.findViewById(R.id.bPractice_deck);`

Then in the next line, do `bPractice.setTag(Integer.valueOf(position))`. This tag will let you utilize the position in your on click method. Since you declare your click method in xml with `android:onClick="startSwipeViewActiviy"` you now need to create your method (as opposed to setting the listener programmatically and using onClick)

```
public void startSwipeViewActivity(View v){
    switch((Integer) v.getTag()){
         case 0:
             // Do stuff for case 0
             break;
         case 1:
             // Do stuff for case 1
             break;
         // Continue for all other cases
     }
}
```

I haven't been able to test this, but it should at least get you going in the right direction. If it doesn't work let me know why and when I get a chance to test it I can likely figure out where I went wrong.